# Faster execution in c++ structure creation

Tags: c++, structure

I am working on c++, I have a structure with all most 100 `float` variables within it, and i am going to `initialize` them with value `0` in no argument constructor ,so which way it is faster?

Type 1:

```
struct info
{
  //no argument constructor
 info();

 float x1;
 float x2;
 .
 .
 .
 float x100;

}Info;   

info::info()
{
  float x1 = 0; 
  float x2 =0;
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  float x100 = 0; 

}
//creation 
Info* info1 = new Info();
```

Type2 :

```
typedef struct info
{
  float x1;
  float x2;
  .
  .
  .
  .
  float x100;
 }Info;

Info* infoIns = new Info;
memset(infoIns,0,sizeof(Info));
```

Comment: Why not keep an array.

Comment: In C++ there is no need to use `typedef` for structures.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : thanx for the reply , but if i am having char, unchar ushort type of variable then i can not use array

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : thanx, i'll keep it in mind

Comment: you have 100 members of varying types called x1 ... x100. How the hell do you expect to maintain something like that?

Comment: Your first example does not initialize the structure's members: you're simply declaring local variables in your constructor, that happen to have the same name (and thus mask) the structure's members. Also, you should take the habit of using the constructor's initializer list rather than assigning the variables in the constructor's body.

Answer (score 1):

One hundred variables called x1 .. x100 just CALLS out to be an array (or if the number varies, perhaps using a vector)

In which case `std::fill(x, x+100, 0.0f)` would probably beat all of the choices above.

A better solution is probably to just initialize the whole object:

```
Info* infoIns = new Info();
```

or

```
Info infoIns = {};  // C++11
```

or

```
Info infoIns = Info();
```

Whenever it's a question of performance, the ONLY answer that applies is "what you can measure". I can sit here and explain exactly why in my experience, on my machine (or my machines) method A is faster than method B or method C. But if you are using a different compiler, or have a different processor, that may not apply at all, because the compiler you use is doing something different.

Regardless of which is "faster", you should use a constructor to set the values to zero. If you want to use `memset`, then by all means do so, but inside the constructor. That way, you won't find some place in the code where you FORGOT to set one of your structures to zero before trying to use it. Bear in mind that setting a struct/class to zero using `memset` is very dangerous. If the class or struct has virtual member functions (or contain some object that does), this will most likely overwrite the VPTR, which describes the virtual functions. That is a bad thing. So if you want to use memset, use it with `x1` and a size of `100 *sizeof(float)` (but using an array is probably a better choice again).

Comment: No need for `std::fill`, just value initialize the array in the constructor's initialization list.

Comment: I was more thinking of the case of "no constructor" - which I then went on to explain is a poor idea anyway.

Comment: Ah OK. Then, value initialize the object. `Info inf{}` or `Info inf = Info()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of measurement, clearing will likely be faster but much much nastier, and, if the code you've written is what you actually implemented, the clearing will actually work a lot better. The 2nd way you have is not particularly good style in any case, and you should use member initialisation.

I'd be more inclined to use a `std::array` (C++11) or a `std::vector` or even a plain array in any case.

Answer (score 0):

2nd version, apart from already mentioned flaws, actually doesn't guarantee that float values will be 0.0 after memset.

### 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]

8
`...

The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined.

...`

Thus you can end up with non zero values in your floating points in case of weird float representation.